Как создать создать sleep в "отдельном" потоке Lua без использования сторонних библиотек?
Дело в том, что в движке, который я использую, отсутствует поддержка библиотек и вырезана библиотека os.
Есть time.uptime().
Вот нерабочий вариант (неизвестная ошибка в corutine.yield()):
function sleep(s)
    local upt = time.uptime()
    while ((time.uptime() - upt) < s) do
        coroutine.yield()
    end
end

Мне нужно, чтобы приостанавливалось только выполнение скрипта, но не останавливался основной поток движка (в том смысле, что другие скрипты работали) (да, Lua в том же потоке, что и движок (а конкретно физика и поворот камеры)

Все вопросы к движку, сильно сомневаюсь что это технически возможно реализовать без его участия

@andreymal Сами сорутины есть, но чёт не работает
